# What does mvregress returns?

Tags: matlab, regression

Conside the following `.m` code

```
x_0 = x(start:start+size);
x_s1 = x(start-2:start+size-2);
x_s2 = x(start-4:start+size-4);
y_0 = y(start:start+size);

XX = [x_0 x_s1 x_s2];

beta = mvregress(XX,y_0);
```

after that `beta` is...

```
beta =

    0.0851
   -0.0946
    0.0102
```

But I suppose it to be a column of size `4` as a regression is something like `y_t = a + b_1 * x1_t + b_2 * x2_t + b_3 * x3_t`. So I did not get `a`.

Can someone tell me what is done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*Note that in Matlab, `size` is a build in function, so you shouldn't use it as an integer...*

It seems there are nothing wrong. We don't see `x`, and `y` so I assume they are columns.

According to the [`mvregress`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvregress.htm) documentation, `beta` will be at size of 3 since `XX` has 3 columns.

> If you specify X as a single n-by-K design matrix, then mvregress returns beta as a column vector of length K. For example, if X is a 20-by-5 design matrix, then beta is a 5-by-1 column vector.

I'm not sure about your `x` data, but the way you wrote `XX`, it looks like there is no constant term (what you called `a`). If you want to calculate a constant term, you can add a column of ones on the left of your matrix `XX`.

```
XX = [ones(size, 1) x_0 x_s1 x_s2];
```

Beta should be of size 4 and the result should look like:

```
beta =

    xxxxxx  % this is a
    0.0851  % b1
   -0.0946  % b2
    0.0102  % b3
```